# Merge 3 .csv into one file with different number of columns

Tags: csv, r, matlab

I have 3 .csv files and I want to merge them together to one .csv file which can be in R or Matlab.
The files are:

```
1597 obs of 167 variables;
160 obs of 167 variables;
533 obs of 146 variables
```

I have tried vertical concatenating them in MatLab by adding extra columns of NaN, however I can't get the columns to align in the correct positions. I tried the merge function in R, but keep coming back to the no. of columns issue, with no luck.

I would appreciate any help!

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest using Python and its `csv` library, which is really handy.

Comment: do the csv files have the same field names? what's the field separator? please add some example rows or share it in gist (or similar)

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), if you have in example these 3 CSV files

```
cat input01.csv
a,b
1,2

cat input02.csv
a,c
7,3

cat input03.csv
a,b,c
9,12,1
```

and you run `mlr --csv unsparsify input0*csv >output.csv`, you will have

```
+---+----+---+
| a | b  | c |
+---+----+---+
| 1 | 2  | - |
| 7 | -  | 3 |
| 9 | 12 | 1 |
+---+----+---+
```

Using in example these two input files:

- https://pastebin.com/L73pHaKF (the name is input_01.csv)
- https://pastebin.com/XAuqF1dx (the name is input_02.csv)

and running

```
mlr --csv unsparsify input_0*.csv >output.csv
```

you will have this output CSV

```
+------------------+-----------------+---------------+
| Plastic: Cleaner | Plastic: Drinks | Plastic: Caps |
+------------------+-----------------+---------------+
| -                | 7               | -             |
| 4                | 5               | -             |
| 5                | 3               | -             |
| 2                | -               | 8             |
+------------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

Then install Miller and make some tests.

Comment: i cant get this to work? can you explain it to me please? but yea the output you have is what i am looking for. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Nic could you add in your question an example of one of your input file?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the database. They are all similar except the column and row length vary and not all headers are consistent. They each include the year, date, etc aswel

Comment: @Nic I have added an example in my answer